# Execute a powershell script downloaded from SCM in Jenkins CI

Tags: powershell, jenkins

I am trying to set up a Jenkins job that downloads a number of scripts from SCM and then executes them on the build server.  I am using the [Powershell plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/powershell/).  I am completely unable to execute any of the downloaded PS1 scripts.  No combination of script execution seems to find & execute the script.  I've confirmed the .ps1 file DOES exist, but am unable to execute it from the Jenkins PowerShell plug-in.

Here is the build step script:

```
dir env:
$file = $ENV:WORKSPACE + '\Download-TrainingImages.ps1'
Write-Host 'This is my file ' $file
Get-ChildItem .

. .\Download-TrainingImages.ps1
.\Download-TrainingImages.ps1
& .\Download-TrainingImages.ps1
powershell.exe -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy ByPass -File $file
& $file
```

And the result is variations of:

```
The term '.\Download-TrainingImages.ps1' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name,
or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
```

I also just verified that `ExecutionPolicy` should be fine.  The value of `GetExecutionPolicy -List` is:

```
@{Scope=MachinePolicy; ExecutionPolicy=Undefined} 
@{Scope=UserPolicy; ExecutionPolicy=Undefined} 
@{Scope=Process; ExecutionPolicy=Bypass} 
@{Scope=CurrentUser; ExecutionPolicy=Undefined} 
@{Scope=LocalMachine; ExecutionPolicy=Bypass}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm an idiot.  I misspelled the name of the script file in source control.

FWIW, here is my final script:

```
$file = $ENV:WORKSPACE + '\Download-TrainingImages.ps1'
& $file -param1 param1
```